# Limit/rotation of ~/.xsession-errors?

Tags: linux, x-windows

My `~/.xsession-errors` file grows very fast and I'd like to set a limit on its size. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should realy try to solve the problems that cause the file to grow.

Comment: Sure! But the thing is some packaged applications write their logs there because of some inner issues and it's not my fault :)

Comment: @o_O: Then that's the problem you need to solve, not this one.

Comment: I find this puritan attitude problematic. In an ideal world where we have time for everything, maybe. In this world one is more often confronted with the choice between debugging the innocuous warning messages of some obscure program, and doing some actual work while keeping the disk less than full. The choice is easy for most.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to install a cron job that moves the file away when it grows too large, with a line similar to (untested)

```
0,31 * * * *  f=$HOME/.xsession.sh; wc -c < $f | perl -lne 'exit ($_ > 1024*1024)' || mv $f $f.bak
```

See

```
man 5 crontab
```

for details.

Comment: Usually removing/truncating is not a good idea for logs: the application that writes there will still have the file handle opened. So, the file either continues to grow even though it was deleted. There should be a way to tell Xorg to reopen its log files.

Comment: Ouch.  You're right, Xorg keeps the logfile open, and there doesn't appear to be a signal you can send it to make it reopen its logfile, so my idea doesn't work.